# Cannot insert values in sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sequences

```
CREATE SEQUENCE CountBy1
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 0;

CREATE TABLE TEST_SEQ (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO TEST_SEQ values (NEXT VALUE FOR CountBy1,'Manoj Pandey');
```

shows this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
```

Comment: Which query is getting the error?

Comment: On http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns002.htm#i1006157 I don't see `NEXT VALUE FOR` as a possible syntax.

Comment: Trivial syntax error arising from failure to read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_SEQ values (CountBy1.NEXTVAL,'Manoj Pandey');
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the next value in the sequence order, you need to use *`nextval`*.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_SEQ values (CountBy1.nextval,'Manoj Pandey');
```

The `ID` field would be assigned the next number from the `TEST_SEQ` sequence.

Refer this for more info: [SEQUENCE EXAMPLE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)